# Angular2 first response to POST request undefined

Tags: angular, http-post

I have a simple method that makes a POST request

```
postData(){
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  var json = JSON.stringify({email: 'Admin', password: 'Admin'});

  return this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/addressbook_rest/api/v1/contacts/login',  json , 
    {headers: headers});

}
```

Then from another component I call the above method

```
onLogin() {
  this._service.postData().map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
    data => { this.loggedin = data },
    err => { console.log(err); }
  );

  console.log(this.loggedin);
}
```

The problem is that on the first call, the variable this.loggedin is undefined but after that I get what I want( this.loggedin=true). I don't know why it only gets it from the second time.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, it's because the request is handled asynchronously. This means that `console.log(this.loggedIn);` will return undefined for the first time because it's outside the subscribe callback. It's executed before receiving the request response.

You should use something like that:

```
onLogin() {
  this._service.postData().map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.loggedin = data;
      console.log(this.loggedin); // <-------
    },
    err => { console.log(err); }
  );
}
```

Comment: But I need this.loggedin after the POST in an IF. What should I do to have the value of this.loggedin there?      If(!this.loggedin) {this.errorMsg = 'Failed to login';}

Comment: To fix your first problem, you could initialize your `loggedIn` property to `false`. Otherwise, you need to think your application asynchronously. I don't know exactly your code but I would see something like that rather: `this._service.login(this.user).subscribe(loggedIn => { if (!loggedIn) {this.errorMsg = 'Failed to login'; } });` See what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the post request is asynchronous. you should check your `this.loggedin` inside subscribe function or inside map function. Nothing is stored in `this.loggedin` at the time you print it on `console` it will be updated after successful ajax call.

See this service [here](https://github.com/khanstudio-github/Angular2AppASPNet/blob/master/Angular2StarterApp/Angular2StarterApp/app/services/dragon.service.ts) hope it will help you solve your problem. **[dragon.service.ts](https://github.com/khanstudio-github/Angular2AppASPNet/blob/master/Angular2StarterApp/Angular2StarterApp/app/services/dragon.service.ts)**

---

To check it after POST use `.then()` it is a callback of successful promise. It will run when your ajax call is returned. You should console.log() in there.

Comment: You can download my project from Github. It is working with POST and GET request. 
https://github.com/khanstudio-github/Angular2AppASPNet


Can you share your final code or error ? As It would be easy to debug your error